# NodeJS - Using form-data npm / https to Automaticlly Login without Opening Window

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Discord Bot, but before adding in a line of code to let it login for me via NodeJS I need to find out how to login with NodeJS, so I found a npm called form-data. I saw it has the potential to automatically login through forms on its npm page but I am still left with the question of how I would do it.

I have a few subscriptions on several websites, but I am not entirely sure how I could search those websites without my bot being logged into my accounts, so I am left with the question of how do I use the npm form-data to login to websites for me via a command in a server. At this stage all I really want is to setup a .js I can launch to login to a site for me. Thanks in advance!

**Where my code currently is:**

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const jQ = require('jQuery');
const FormData = require('form-data');
var form = new FormData();
var jQuery = new jQ().noConflict();

//Sample I took from a previous stackOverflow that I came across, the rest is me trying to figure stuff out.
    if (window.location.indexOf("mail.google.com") > -1) {
        // Lets login to Gmail
        jQuery("#Email").val("youremail@gmail.com");
        jQuery("#Passwd").val("superSecretPassowrd");
        jQuery("#gaia_loginform").submit();
    }

var request = https.request({
  method: 'post',
  host: 'spotify.com',
  path: '/nl-NL/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Fnl%2Faccount%2Foverview%2F',
  auth: 'username:password',
  username: 'super secret username!',
  password: 'super secret password!'
});

form.pipe(request);

request.on('response', function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusMessage);
});
```

Comment: What you ask is a bit general and wrong to do. What I mean is that each platform has its own authorization and it really hard to login through the website itself. That is why each platform has an API for that sort of stuff. For spotify you should check [node-spotify-api npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-spotify-api). You don't have to authorize with username and password just use `id` and `client secret` provided from spotify for devs

Comment: thanks for the comment but not all platforms have that easy answer, i dont want to only support spotify with this that was just 1 example.

Comment: Then you should check [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/) or something similar. You can create different strategies(there are many npm ready like `passport-spotify`) and authorize to many web API. I ll repeat the above example is bad practice.